# Wrong Output with Queens Problem on Python

Tags: python, n-queens

I've been working on the Queens problem on an 8 x 8 board but I keep on getting an output with 2 empty rows:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

If `board[4][5] = 1` and `board[5][7] = 1` the output would be correct but I just can't get it to work out the way I want it to. Can somebody help me figure out the problem? I'm not recursively calling the function on purpose as I want to try and solve it this way instead.

Here is my code in Python:

```
def checksquares(board, row, column):
    rowtemp = row
    columntemp = column

    for i in range(0,8):                          
        if board[i][column] == 1:
            return False

    for j in range(0,8):
        if board[row][j] == 1:
            return False

    while rowtemp > 0 and columntemp > 0:          
        rowtemp = rowtemp - 1
        columntemp = columntemp - 1

    while rowtemp < 7 and columntemp < 7:          
        if board[rowtemp][columntemp] == 1:
            return False
        rowtemp = rowtemp + 1
        columntemp = columntemp + 1

    rowtemp = row
    columntemp = column

    while rowtemp > 0 and columntemp < 7:          
        rowtemp = rowtemp - 1
        columntemp = columntemp + 1

    while rowtemp < 7 and columntemp > 0:          
        if board[rowtemp][columntemp] == 1:
            return False
        rowtemp = rowtemp + 1
        columntemp = columntemp - 1

    return True


def placequeens(board, queencount):
    temp = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    for i in range(0,8):
        for j in range(temp[i],8):
            if checksquares(board, i, j) == True:
                board[i][j] = 1
                queencount = queencount + 1
                temp[i] = j
        if board[i] == [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]:
            board[i - 1] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
            if temp[i - 1] < 7:
                temp[i - 1] = temp[i - 1] + 1
            elif temp[i - 1] == 7:
                temp[i - 1] = 7
            temp[i] = 0               
          

    

board = [ [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]

queencount = 0

placequeens(board, queencount)
print(board)
```

Comment: Your diagonal check ignores the rightmost column.

Comment: If you fail to place a queen in one row, you remove the queen from the previous row and keep going with the next row. This gives you two "all zeros" rows in the result.

Comment: So I changed all the 7's to 8's in `def checksquares` And I changed the for loop to a while loop and made changes accordingly. However, I end up getting this: `IndexError: list index out of range` I can't seem to find out the problem behind this as well.